# YouTube, Content ID; Is there a way to check if some content is under copyright?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a live stream that I set up and monitor through YouTube APIs,

It has happened to me that I get the following warning:

`We've detected copyrighted audio in your stream. Your stream may be temporarily blocked.`

Is there a way to check this beforehand, with an API or something, so that I could prevent this content from being streame, before it reaches YouTube?

Note: I know the pedantic answer to this would be: *all content is under copyright*. But please note that many content owners allow their media to be used as long as they can monetize from it (that's pretty much the spirit of Content ID). Some others don't allow it and that's when you may get a copyright notice.

Comment: Can you provide a example of a video you're tring to check? - I think there's a property which returns true or false if the video has something to do with copyright, but, I don't remember very well right now.

Comment: It's probably the "license" field, but in practice is useless. Is never up to date, sometime is not defined, etc... etc..